# behaviour of unordered_map reserve

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, unordered-map, lru

The maximum size of my collection (an unordered_map) is known beforehand, so I want to reserve memory at start up for optimization. Does the member function `reserve()` achieve that purpose? The documentation says it will reserve the right number of buckets to contain N elements. Does that mean it will reserve space for N elements and reuse those as long as I don't have more than N elements in the map? The purpose is for LRU caching so an element has to be evicted, before a new one is added. I just want to make sure that memory is reused when an `erase_element()` is followed by `insert_newelement()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The [std:unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) has the member function [reserve()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/reserve) exactly for that purpose.

Comment: Ok it is good to know. I was just not sure if it will reserve memory for values. I read that the standard map<> container only reserves memory for the keys and uses dynamic new/delete for the elements.. Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, `std::map` does not have `reserve`.

Comment: It seems also GCC's unordered_map does not have a reserve() so I don't know what to do about that. For a map, I was thinking of the case I read about a memory pool being used to get a  fixed size map, but then it still uses new/delete because of the underlying binary tree.

Comment: The version of GCC I use, 4.8.2, [does have `std::unordered_map::reserve`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a00958.html#a2eee23bd13796426f3018c8a9341202f). Which version of GCC are you using?

As far as `std::map` is concerned, you could use a special allocator, that manages a memory pool.